# Place to convert English sentence to interlinear gloss with Chinese sentence

Tags: grammar, writing

I'm wondering if there is any free online tool that offers the ability to type in a sentence and have it provide a literal "[interlinear gloss](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php)" of the original English text in the translated Chinese. So for example you would [type in](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/sentsearch.php?searchMode=E&word=last+night):

> It wasn't very hot last night.

And instead of just getting [this](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/sentsearch.php?searchMode=E&word=last+night):

> 昨晚不是很热。

...which is nice, but it's not enough. It would be nice if it divided it into individual words and put there literal meaning next to it, sort of like:

```
[昨]   [晚]   [不]       [是]   [很热]
last   night  not       very   hot
```

I'm not sure if that is correct, but something like that. That would make it easier to learn.

Comment: 昨[last]晚[night]不是[wasn't]很[very]热[hot]。

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs maybe you can find word level translate here. Overall, it maybe a NLP job if you want precision. If not asked for precision, Firstly translate english to chinese, then use tools like `jieba` https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba to segment words, finally foreach words translate to English again. But I think the final result is useless for complex sentences.

Comment: And all example sentences in http://dict.youdao.com/ has similar function, you can use mouse to find translation of each words. And you can search example sentences either for chinese or english.

Comment: Have you tried "Perapera Chinese Popup Dictionary" as an extension in your web browser?  It interactively does what you want, but one word at a time.  ("昨晚" is one word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I had seen this question sooner since this is exactly what I use [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%98%A8%E6%99%9A%E4%B8%8D%E6%98%AF%E5%BE%88%E7%83%AD%E3%80%82) for:

[image]

Comment: Yabla is such a great resource, thanks.

Comment: This is not a "real" interlinear gloss - it just gets definitions for each word that has been segmented. It doesn't even use part of speech to filter out definitions from the correct part of speech (probably because CC-CEDICT specifically doesn't include any part of speech information, and have refused to add it).

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach is to copy/paste the translation output into [Pleco](https://www.pleco.com/).  E.g.:

[image: 昨晚不是很热]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a tool, but this can be done with some tools combined.

First, use any translation services to get the Chinese text.

Then use a 分词 library to split words.

And there are many ways to add pinyin.

I will write a script, if I can't found one later.